# error while registering large xml schema in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is there any solution to register the large XML schema in oracle.

when i tried to register XML schema (which is <32KB) using dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema it was succesful.

But when the XML schema is large in size (>32KB), there is an error message:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 49:
PLS-00172: string literal too long
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Answer (score 1):

[`DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_xmlsch.htm#i1003177) is overloaded to take several different types:

```
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(
    schemaurl        IN  VARCHAR2,
    schemadoc        IN  VARCHAR2,
    local            IN  BOOLEAN := TRUE,
    gentypes         IN  BOOLEAN := TRUE,
    genbean          IN  BOOLEAN := FALSE,
    gentables        IN  BOOLEAN := TRUE,
    force            IN  BOOLEAN := FALSE,
    owner            IN  VARCHAR2 := NULL,
    enablehierarchy  IN  PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.ENABLE_CONTENTS,
    options          IN  PLS_INTEGER := 0);
```

Takes the `schemadoc` argument as a `VARCHAR2` which in PL/SQL is [limited to 32,767 bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943).

```
DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(
   schemaurl        IN  VARCHAR2, 
   schemadoc        IN  CLOB, 
   local            IN  BOOLEAN := TRUE, 
   gentypes         IN  BOOLEAN := TRUE, 
   genbean          IN  BOOLEAN := FALSE,
   force            IN  BOOLEAN := FALSE,
   owner            IN  VARCHAR2 := NULL,
   options          IN  PLS_INTEGER := 0);
```

Takes the `schemadoc` argument as a `CLOB` which is [limited to 128TB](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/datatypes.htm#LNPLS99943).

You do not specify what the datatypes you are using to call the procedure but it would appear that you are passing a `VARCHAR2` and you probably want to pass a `CLOB` (or one of the other types with a larger limit).

Comment: Thank you for the response.
I tried to execute like below:

DECLARE
schemaURL   VARCHAR2(50);
schemaDoc   CLOB;
BEGIN   
   dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(schemaURL   => 'xsd2.xsd', 
                                 schemaDoc   => 'large XML schema'
END;

Comment: You are still calling it with a string literal not a CLOB. Try: `DECLARE schemaURL VARCHAR2(50); schemaDoc CLOB := 'large XML schema'; BEGIN dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(schemaURL => 'xsd2.xsd', schemaDoc => schemaDoc ); END;`

Comment: I use your query, and still it returns with the same error message.        In place of 'large XML schema' i replace with my XML schema  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                              <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> ............... </xsd:schema>'

Comment: `'....'` is a string literal - if it has more than 32k bytes it will throw the error. Either load the CLOB from a file or if you are going to initialise it with a string literal then split it into <32k chunks.

Comment: Thank you, how i can load the file directly to the CLOB variable, can it be done during the variable initialization itself?

Comment: Search the internet for "oracle load clob from file".

Comment: Thank you.. i got the solution to load the file into the CLOB variable and to perform the DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA.

Comment: Just want to know, xmlisvalid function returns '1' if the xml is valid and '0' if the xml is invalid. Is there anyway to see what is the error message or log when the xml is invalid (i mean when it is '0')?

Comment: That sounds like something you should ask another question about.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to read the XML Schema from the file system using a BFILE, or preload it into the XDB Repository and then use the registerURI method